# JQuery UI sortable creates endless placeholders on mousedown

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

Trying to create a simple sortable list

```
    $('#sortable').sortable();
    $('#sortable').disableSelection();
```

But the result is **endless number of placeholders** created on mousedown. I am using **twitter bootstrap** for the application, if that helps!

Comment: Nothing else, just those two lines and <ul> element with id 'sortable'.

Comment: Same issue here when trying to nest them. Mine works find for the inner items (li in your case), but when trying to nest <ul> into <ul> it seems to drop into itself and infinite loop.

Comment: I threw the lines on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ue2hA/
ans it seems Ok.